# System.Resources.MissingManifesResourceException - What's causing this?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

I just added an image resource to my assembly via the Resources tab in the project properties of my project. The resource is a PNG image. Now when I load the assembly, I'm getting the error shown below. This is occurring in VS 2010.

```
System.Resources.MissingManifestResourceException: Could not find any resources 
appropriate for the specified culture or the neutral culture.
```

Anyone know what is causing this?

Thanks very much.

Comment: When you *load* the assembly?  You need to post a snippet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Did you set the resource to be embedded?
- Check the path in the project explorer within VS, suppose you have this path (from the root of the project), root -> resources -> foobar.png, then the full resource path would be `[namespace of your project]` followed by `resources.foobar.png`, for example, suppose the namespace is 'foobar' then it would be "foobar.resources.foobar.png"